# autocomplete control in kendo mobile

Tags: kendo-ui, jquery-autocomplete, kendo-mobile

is there a way to do this also with Telerik Kendo Mobile:

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/3/27/Example-of-Autocomplete-in-jQuery-Mobile

Answer (score 1):

Use the listview with the filtering feature: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/listview/filtering.html

Answer (score 0):

There is an AutoComplete control that is not in the mobile specific controls.

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/autocomplete/index.html

If you are interested in using it I would jsut suggest testing and making sure that is performant on the mobile systems. The demo works perfectly on my Galaxy S3.